# NSIS script - Uninstall.exe file alone not getting deleted

Tags: nsis

I am using the below statements to delete the files and subdirectories from the installed directory.

```
RMDir /r "$INSTDIR\*.*"
RMDir "$INSTDIR"
```

While uninstalling, it doesn't delete the uninstall.exe file alone from the installed directory.

Please let me know your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you tried the `/REBOOTOK`flag?
2. Take notice of this warning from the [scripting reference](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/RMDir):

> **Warning**: using RMDir /r $INSTDIR in the uninstaller is not safe.
>   Though it is unlikely, the user might select to install to the Program
>   Files folder and so this command will wipe out the entire Program
>   Files folder, including other programs that has nothing to do with the
>   uninstaller. The user can also put other files but the program's files
>   and would expect them to get deleted with the program. Solutions are
>   [available](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Uninstall_only_installed_files) for easily uninstalling only files which were installed by
>   the installer.

Comment: Yes. It is working after I reboot the system. Is it a way to delete it while uninstalling itself?